# Are creature effects considered an Instant?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I played Magic a long time ago, and I remember activated abilities on creatures were considered instants. Reading through the rules today, it isn't quite clear to me. The reason I am wondering is for the combination of [Prodigal Pyromancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205231) and [Fire Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234702). The does the Fire Servant's doubling apply to the Prodigal Pyromancer's "{T}: Prodigal Pyromancer deals 1 damage to target creature or player."?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the doubling does not apply. Creature abilities *are* fast effects, a class which includes instants. But instants, like sorceries, are a distinct spell type.

Comment: This is substantially correct, though the term "fast effect" was dropped from Magic a loooong time ago.  Most creature abilities do happen at the same speed as an instant, but that doesn't make them instant spells, not by a long chalk!